# Como cargar la imagen de una carpeta local desde un servidor?

Tags: php, imagen, archivo, rutas

Tengo un problema y no consigo solucionarlo. La cosa es que tengo un input type file que carga una imagen de una carpeta en local y a la hora de pulsar insertar se sube a la bd. Quiero hacer eso mismo pero desde un servidor, pero claro necesito la ruta de la carpeta y no consigo que lo haga bien.

Tengo esto:

```
$nom_archivo=$_FILES['imagen']['name']; // Para conocer el nombre del archivo
        $ruta = "C:\Users\abc\Pictures\imagenes" . $nom_archivo;  // La ruta del archivo contiene el nuevo nombre y el tipo de extension
        $archivo = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']; //el arhivo a subir
        $subir=move_uploaded_file($archivo, $ruta); //se sube el archivo
```

Luego con un prepare paso `$_FILES['imagen']`
**Obviamente la ruta esta mal, he probado con otras y me sube la ruta que pongo a las carpetas del servidor y no deja borrarlas.**
Eso en local cambiando la ruta funciona perfectamente. No se si se entiende el problema que tengo, ya se que subiendo las imagenes a la bd directamente y con un select por ejemplo podría cargar la ruta y ya , pero necesito ayuda con el input type=file.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es que ocupes la función de php realpath(); [php -realpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.realpath.php) esto te devolverá la ruta del archivo actual.

```
    $r = realpath('archivo.jpg');
    echo $r;

   // salida ej : /var/www/html/proyecto/archivo.jpg
```

espero te ayude, siempre es bueno revisar laa docu de php.

Answer (score 0):

¿Porqué no intentas cargando la carpeta en tu sitio? Así de esta forma sólo tendrías que llamar a la ruta desde tu servidor web.

Saludos.

Comment: La zona de respuestas no es espacio para dejar preguntas o comentarios al OP respecto de su pregunta